# Server responce 200 to url that does not exist

Tags: php, url, logging

I have such records in my Apache 2.2 one of the virtual hosts access_log file:

GET /index.php/**image-gallery/animals/57-wobbegone**?c=2&s=8&p=384&l=ru HTTP/1.1" 200 19549 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

or like this:

GET /index.php/**using-joomla/extensions/components/news-feeds-component/news-feed-category/2-new-joomla-extensions**?c=8&s=49&p=392&l=ru HTTP/1.1" 200 20961 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

The **bolded** folders does not exsist at the server, but clients (Bots) does not get 404 error.

Q1: How to prevent/configure it?

Ii is possible to write anything to the right of index.php  e.g. (http://domainName/index.php?c=0&s=0&l=ee/blablabla)

Q2: is it ok?

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

If index.php exists, the part `/image-gallery/animals/57-wobbegone` is ignored, the rest after the `?` are GET parameters `c=2&s=8&p=384&l=ru` and passed to the script. You will see the whole string in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. You could examine this as first action and if you detect other characters than the `?` after `index.php`, then possibly return a 500-error with the header() function of php.